# Facebook Graph API for iphone

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

check this [Facebook GraphAPI](https://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API)

I am using this Graph API. It is not showing login screen every time ,I start this app.And I can see the results on console. I want to know how can I save result of method in NSDictionary to display it in tableView or some label..Method is

```
-(IBAction)getMeFeedButtonPressed:(id)sender {
FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphGet:@"me/feed" withGetVars:nil];
NSLog(@"getMeFeedButtonPressed:  %@", fb_graph_response.htmlResponse);
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: Following the link the first comment on that page is _'!!NOTE!!: this project is no longer maintained. The official Facebook/iOS SDK can be found here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-iphone-sdk'_ - is there a reason you're using old libraries?

Comment: The link you specified is FBConnect and Graph API Is new thats why I downloaded that.I am confused which is new?

Comment: [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app) and what is this

Comment: user640780...okay it is not maintained but dont worry it is working

Comment: and what is it showing everytime?? success?? :)

Comment: yaa and all the methods are showing output on console.please tell me which library I should prefer?

Comment: prefer this one only..its good written..try to implement it on your screen..It also seemed hard to me but it will done dont worry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did this while using your kind-a stuff..

```
NSString *customString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"me/feed"];
NSLog(@"here responce is for %@",customString);

FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphGet:customString withGetVars:nil];
NSLog(@"getMeFeedButtonPressed:  %@", fb_graph_response.htmlResponse);


//parse our json
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
NSDictionary *facebook_response = [parser objectWithString:fb_graph_response.htmlResponse error:nil];   
//  [facebook_response ]
[parser release];

//NSString *feed;
//  NSString *feed2;
NSMutableArray *feed =(NSMutableArray *) [facebook_response objectForKey:@"data"];

//  NSMutableArray *feed1=(NSMutableArray *) [feed valueForKey:@"type"];
NSLog(@"%@",feed);

int index;
NSString* strMessage;


for (index=0; index<[feed count]; index++) {

    //NSLog(@"........%@",[feed objectAtIndex:2]);
    NSString* forTable=[feed objectAtIndex:index];

    NSString *tempString = [forTable valueForKey:@"type"];
    NSLog(@"--------%@",tempString);

    if([tempString isEqualToString:@"status"]){
        NSLog(@"do something with status");
        strMessage=[forTable valueForKey:@"message"];
        NSString* strTime   =[forTable valueForKey:@"created_time"];
        NSLog(@"\n %@ \n %@ ",strMessage,strTime);
        [friendsArray addObject:strMessage];

    }
    else if([tempString isEqualToString:@"link"]){
        NSLog(@"do something with link");
        strMessage=[forTable valueForKey:@"message"];
        NSString* nameStr   =[forTable valueForKey:@"name"];
        NSLog(@"\n %@ \n %@ ",strMessage,strTime);
        [friendsArray addObject:strMessage];
                    [nameArray addObject:nameStr];

    }
    else if([tempString isEqualToString:@"photo"]){
        NSLog(@"do something with photo");
        strMessage=[forTable valueForKey:@"link"];
        NSString* strTime   =[forTable valueForKey:@"created_time"];
        NSLog(@"\n %@ \n %@ ",strMessage,strTime);
        [friendsArray addObject:strMessage];
    }
    else if([tempString isEqualToString:@"video"]){
        NSLog(@"do something with video");
        strMessage=[forTable valueForKey:@"name"];
        NSString* strTime   =[forTable valueForKey:@"created_time"];
        NSLog(@"\n %@ \n %@ ",strMessage,strTime);
        [friendsArray addObject:strMessage];
    }

}       
NSLog(@"%d",[friendsArray count]);
    NSLog(@"%d",[friendsArray count]);
for(int i =0 ; i < [friendsArray count] ; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"\nelement %d is :%@",i,[friendsArray objectAtIndex:i]);
}


FaceBookTable *detailViewController = [[FaceBookTable alloc] initWithNibName:@"FaceBookTable" bundle:nil];
// ...
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
detailViewController.dummyArray=friendsArray;
    detailViewController.dummyNameArray=nameArray;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
[detailViewController release];
```

after doing this you will have all the data in Feed1. Now parse them according to your requirement of what you want to show in your table :)

Comment: Giving warning 'NSString' maynot respond to JSONVALUE

Comment: Hmm..there is not any changes in console output.I want to display this output {id " " ,...} in Tableview like profile of user on facebook

Comment: okay..but now you can see organized o/p in your console right?? tell me so i can tell you more

Comment: Yes organized o/p was already shown and your code is showing same output.I want user interface.

Comment: okay...this is not possible..how could you see the organsied o/p before using json parsing?

Comment: what do you see right now? paste here so I can tell you how to move on next step

Comment: Try my code -(IBAction)getMeButtonPressed:(id)sender and see the output

Comment: but was it organized?? i mean you must have crunch of things after "data"

Comment: sorry :( my mistake.your code is giving correct output.Thanks for great help

Comment: I will try to get this in UITableView

Comment: okay...best of luck :) and if you want to show it in the table..remember..take this whole thing into the string..from that string choose the element you want to show on the table and take them in the array..now show that array on the table..that's it

Comment: Hi I am not getting how to to display it in tableView

Comment: are you there ?? what are you getting??

Comment: I got the values in NSDictionary and I am able to display name and message value on console.When I tried same thing in table view it is also displaying value there but app is crashing on scrolling

Comment: entry1 = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
entry1 = [feed1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [entry1 objectForKey:@"link"];

Comment: All is working fine but Problem is with memory management It is crashing -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6374920

Comment: I tried your approach everything is showing on console.Now what about table view

Comment: i got the problem now.i have edited the answer here..go and implement it in your getMeFeed method..and tell me what are you getting..

Comment: output is same as old code.. some difference in last lines and app is crashing after this

Comment: have you declared friendsArray there?? in your .h file

Comment: and allocated it?? and delete your tableview vala class now

Comment: in that example check getmefeed method

Comment: [link]http://www.raywenderlich.com/1578/how-to-get-a-user-profile-with-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app  Can I use this instead of that we are using?

Comment: Hey it is crashing for my API KEY . with your key it is working fine

Comment: do something with status
2011-05-05 15:48:22.750 MiniTwit[4668:207] 
 (null) 
 2011-05-05T07:30:27+0000 
2011-05-05 15:48:22.795 MiniTwit[4668:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil object at 4'

Comment: what is the fourth status of the facebook profile you are accessing?

Comment: I used Other Key And this is working but showing messages in tableview is not my profile messages//:o

Comment: yes...it is obvious because its news feed not current fee...do me/home in place of me/feed

Comment: last question...Y it is showing link description I want to show message and name only

Comment: what do you want to get ?? Name or Id??

Comment: NO , I want to display Message with sender name on wall

Comment: edited...in the link section here..now do one thing..in tableviewController...cell.detailText lable..show that array..